# User opens multiple windows of your site, can you identify each window

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm trying to figure out if you can identify the multiple windows that a user may open of the same site. So I want the initial window to be named window1. If they open a new window, I want it to be named window2.

Is there a way to do this? This is a .Net application.

Comment: Any comment on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Thoughts:**

I do not believe you can figure out multiple windows of an application within one browser.  Since resources are shared a user can open 10 tabs of your application in Chrome and you would not know.

But if your user was to open up an Internet Explorer tab next there would be multiple sessions taking place at that time.  And depending on how you are storing the session state you should be able to access that information.

If you use the same browser the Session ID will be the same.

If you use different ones they will have different IDs.

On each Page Load the browser sends this id.

Log in to Facebook or Gmail in one tab and then open another. Did you have to log in again?

**Testing:**

In Chrome this is easy to find.  Press F12 -> Resources Tab -> Cookies ->  Your App -> Session ID.

"The SessionID value is randomly generated by ASP.NET and stored in a non-expiring session cookie in the browser. "  <-- This is what Chrome tells you about it.

Open multiple tabs and you will see that the ID does not change.

Open multiple browsers and you will see that it does over browser.

**Recommendation:**

My recommmendation would be to read up on Session State.  :)

[A MSDN resource on SessionID.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WEB.SESSIONSTATE.HTTPSESSIONSTATE.SESSIONID%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)